# Send a list of strings to an ASP.net api controller with vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

**Send a list of strings to an ASP.net core api controller with vanilla Javascript**

This might sound simple but something is going wrong and i'm not sure what. I am trying to send a list of strings such as `[ "something", "something else", "Another string" ]` to my api post controller in ASP.Net Core.

**My Controller looks like this**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<MyModel> Name([FromBody] List<string> list)
        {

            // Do something... 

            return NoContent();
        }
```

**And my Javascript looks like this**

```
async function apiCall() {

                const response = await fetch("URL", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ list: [ "something", "something else", "Another string" ] })
                }}
```

When ever I call the `apiCall()` funcation it posts data to the controller but the data `List` is always null. How do I correctly post this data?

Comment: Your model is not an array of string, but an object with an array of string as property, all the best

Comment: Thanks it was an easy fix. When I change the body to `body: JSON.stringify([ "something", "something else", "Another string" ])` It works!

Comment: sometimes happens ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
body: JSON.stringify({ list: [ "something", "something else", "Another string" ] })
```

To

```
body: JSON.stringify([ "something", "something else", "Another string" ])
```

And it works. I was not sending an array of strings but an object with an array of strings as a property.